# I am setting up a Userform and how do I do next row for a specific range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a Userform that will input information into excel. But I want it to set up on a specific range. I am trying to set it up so it will go to the next row when I click "Save" on the Userform.

Right now, when I click "Save" the second time, instead of inputting the data to the next available line, it would go up instead of down.

```
Private Sub cbSave_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkBook.ActiveSheet
LastRow = ws.Range("A16", "K21").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Cells(LastRow,1) = Me.tbApple
ws.Cells(LastRow,2) = Me.tbSony
ws.Cells(LastRow,3) = Me.tbWindow

End Sub
```

So the first time I hit "Save", it would be on row 16 which I want. But the second time it would go to Row 14 instead of 17. I want it to go to Row 17.
How would I set it up so it can go to 17?

Also there are data from Cell A22 and down. But the range that I want it to be is only from A16 to K21.

Thank you

Comment: Try `LastRow = ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: yea that didn't work, it would input the data at the very bottom

Answer (score 0):

For each x in selection

‘Do some work

Next x